# Are DOM elements regular javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, dom

I would just like clarity on if the differences between the javascript objects for HTML elements vs regular javascript objects. Do they share a common ancestor in the inheritance chain? Any other differences I should know about?

Comment: Yes, a DOM node is an object representation of the element, hence "Document Object Model", inheriting from the Object constructor.

Comment: But it isn't a regular javascript object. It exists only in web environment.

Comment: It differs from a regular JS object that you might make your self because it is backed by calls that it makes to the browsers native api that you don't have access to in your code.

Comment: DOM elements objects are regular javascript objects that implement WebAPI interfaces (i.e. HTMLTableElement interface)